# Most efficient JavaScript countdown timer implementation

Tags: javascript

I have this timer working already([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/udozuk/3/edit)):

HTML:

```
  <input id="m" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="59"/>
  <input id="s" type="number" value="2" min="0" max="59"/>
  <input id="start" type="button" value="Start!" />
  <output>00:00</output>
```

JavaScript:

```
var o = document.querySelector('output'),
m = document.querySelector('#m')
s = document.querySelector('#s'),
start = document.querySelector('#start');


start.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var mm = parseInt(m.value),
        ss = parseInt(s.value);
    timer = function(){
        if(mm>0){
            if(ss>0){
                ss--;
            }
            else{
                mm--;
                ss = 59;
            }
            setTimeout("timer()", 1000);
            o.value = (mm<10 ? '0' + mm : mm) + ":" + (ss<10 ? '0' + ss : ss);
        }
        else{
            if(ss>0){
                ss--;
                o.value = "00:" + (ss<10 ? '0' + ss : ss);
                setTimeout("timer()", 1000);
            }
        }
    }

    timer();
}, false);
```

It seems a lot of code for just a timer. Is it possible to implement this with less code? Maybe with loops, `Date` object or something else?

This code have problem and that is number of items in call stack when the time is big enough. I tried to write same code with `while` or `for` but I couldn't get a good result.

**MY QUESTION** is how to write this countdown with `for` or `while`?

Answer (score 4):

`document.querySelector("#id")` is just a costly version of `document.getElementById("id")`. `document.getElementById` is the fastest way to select an element in your page (to the smartasses of you: besides `document.head`, `document.body` etc)

`document.querySelector("tagname")` is also just a costly version of `document.getElementsByTagName("tagname")[0]`. Coincidentally, that's the second fastest way to get an element.

`document.querySelector` and its array-like version are only useful for compound statements that are either too long or too difficult to do with "regular" DOM methods. One might argue that if your html is compound and complex, you're doing it wrong, and they'd most likely be right.

If I were you, I'd also do future-you a favor and name your variables in a way that makes sense.

So, what do we have so far?

```
var output = document.getElementsByTagName("output")[0],
    minutes = document.getElementById("m"),
    seconds = document.getElementsById("m"),
    start = document.getElementById("start");
```

Moving on. The event listener is fine, now about parsing integers...

Try this piece of code: `parseInt("08")`. The result is 0. Why, you ask? Well, if you don't pass a radix as a second parameter, `parseInt` will be nice enough to *guess* what you mean. `parseInt` sees that your string begins in a 0 and, of course, assumes the number is in octal! Why wouldn't it be?

Point: either pass a radix like this: `parseInt(string, 10)` or use `parseFloat`, which will always assume a decimal number. Whichever you like best, though I once heard that `parseFloat` is faster, dunno if that's true. I personally prefer `parseFloat`, for no obvious reason

So we get:

```
var mm = parseFloat(minutes.value),
    ss = parseFloat(seconds.value);
```

Magnificent.

This line:

```
timer =
```

Contains one of the most widely made errors in javascript. It's called implied global.

Basically, when you omit the `var` statement, the variable definition list gets appended to the global object (which `window` refers to). So:

```
function foo() { answer = 42; }
foo();
window.answer === 42;
```

Never omit the `var` statement. Even if you *do* wish to append a variable to the global object, do it explicitly (`window.answer = 42;`). Better that then let someone scratch their head trying to figure out how magic variables appeared from seemingly nowhere.

Besides one more thing, your code is fine. What's that other thing, you ask? `setTimeout`

When you pass a string to `setTimeout`, it's the same as calling `eval`. It evaluates the string. That's slow and bad. Instead, pass a function to it:

```
setTimeout(timer, 1000);
```

Since `timer` is a function, you can pass it around like any other value.

Now, one might ask: "How do I call `func` with parameters?"

```
setTimeout(function() {
    func(something, somethingElse);
}, 1000);
//or
setTimeout(func, 1000, something, somethingElse);
```

About your actual code? it's fine. It's not the best piece of code I've ever, but it's not the worse as well. It's not too long for a timer, since all that's done is decrementing and calling itself again. I'd move the `< 10` checks to their own function, but maybe that's because I'm insane and not that "your way" is worse.

---

**tl;dr** Your code contains errors, but other than that, it's fine.

Comment: I don't agree with things you said about `querySelector` because fastness is not a matter here and I just used that selector for ease of code. My main question was how to improve `timer` that is not answered here.

Comment: @Mohsen Yes I did. Right at the end.

Comment: How much I'm close to your ideal? http://jsbin.com/udozuk/8/edit

Comment: @Mohsen Looks finer. You got rid of two points. However, the `timer` variable is still an implied global. Also, is your life dependent on using `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`? You made your html structure a little less obvious to make the selectors much less obvious.

Comment: I hate `id`s! You can see with this code I can have another timer in my page but it's not easy if I had `id` in my code

Comment: @Mohsen `id`s represent elements which *must* be unique. If you have several elements which fit under a single, general name, that's a class for you, and there's `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` browser support is same as `querySelector` while you can do `queryselector("#div .class element[attr]")` but it's like ten line of code if you do this with other selectors

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a loop to do something like this, as that would lock up the user interface. There is nothing happening in the browser as long as your function is running, so the change in the output would simply not show up.

Here are some suggestions:

You have different code for counting down when there is minutes involved and when there isn't, but you can use the same code for both.

You can keep track of the time as seconds, and split it into minutes and seconds when you display it, that simplifies the code a bit.

You can use the function name `timer` in the `setTimeout` call, that way you don't have to declare the function globally.

```
document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click', function(){

  var o = document.querySelector('output');
  var t =
    parseInt(document.querySelector('#m').value, 10) * 60 +
    parseInt(document.querySelector('#s').value, 10);

  var timer = function(){
    if (t > 0) {
      t--;
      var m = Math.floor(t \ 60);
      var s = t % 60;
      o.value = (m < 10 ? '0' : '') + m + ":" + (s < 10 ? '0' : '') + s;
      window.setTimeout(timer, 1000);
    }
  }

  timer();
}, false);
```

Regarding the call stack: The code is not recursive, so it won't build up calls on the call stack. The `timer` function adds itself as an event, it doesn't call itself.

Comment: @Mohsen: Yes, they can be combined, but that's just a matter of preference. It has no impact on performance.

Comment: @Guffa : Hie there! I was wondering if there is optimized code for countdown showing DD:HH:MM:SS . Can you please help me out for this? Thanks !!

Comment: @Dharmraj: For such a long time period you would need to calculate the time as a time difference to get it reasonably accurate, not just using a counter and a timer. Anyway, here are some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642777/looking-for-a-easy-way-to-buildt-a-js-countdown-scriptdays-hours-minutes-seco

Answer (score 1):

If you use seconds instead of a mm:ss to hold your time, everything will be simpler.

Plus, you can encapsulate your reading and writing of values:

```
function readSeconds() {
  return parseInt(m.value, 10) * 60 + parseInt(s.value, 10);
}

function output(seconds) {
  var mm = seconds / 60, ss = seconds % 60;
  o.value = (mm<10 ? '0' + mm : mm) + ":" + (ss<10 ? '0' + ss : ss);
}
```

Then, you can write your start method more easily. Something like:

```
start.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var seconds = readSeconds();
    function timer(){
       seconds--;
       output(seconds);
       setTimeout(timer, 1000);
    }
    timer();
}, false);
```

Obviously this isn't all the details, but a little encapsulation helps quite a bit.